# How to add a list of cookies to selenium remote driver?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-remotedriver

I am trying to add a list of cookies to a selenium chrome instance running remotely, the singular method add_cookie is too slow for my needs with each request taking ~5-10 seconds and roughly 1000-5000 cookies this would become intractable. I have thought of creating a custom Cookie input to the ActionsChains class as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.actions import interaction 
from selenium.webdriver.common.actions.input_device import InputDevice
from selenium.webdriver.common.actions.interaction import (Interaction, Pause)

class CookieInput(InputDevice):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(CookieInput, self).__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.type = interaction.KEY

    def encode(self):
        return {"type": self.type, "id": self.name, "actions": [acts.encode() for acts in self.actions]}

    def create_add_cookie(self, cookie):
        self.add_action(CookieInteraction(self, "addCookie", cookie))

    def create_delete_cookie(self, cookie):
        self.add_action(CookieInteraction(self, "deleteCookie", cookie))
        
class CookieInteraction(Interaction):

    def __init__(self, source, type_, cookie):
        super(CookieInteraction, self).__init__(source)
        self.type = type_
        self.cookie = cookie 

    def encode(self):
        return {"type": self.type, "value": self.cookie}
    
class CookieActions(Interaction):
    def __init__(self, source):
        if not source:
            source = CookieInput(KEY)
        self.source = source
        super(CookieActions, self).__init__(source) 
        
    def add_cookie(self, cookie):
        return self._cookie_action("create_add_cookie", cookie)

    def delete_cookie(self, cookie):
        return self._cookie_action("create_add_cookie", cookie)
    
    def add_cookies(self, cookies):
        for cookie in cookies:
            self.add_cookie(cookie)
        return self

    def delete_cookies(self, cookies):
        for cookie in cookies:
            self.delete_cookie(cookie)
        return self
    
    def _cookie_action(self, action, cookie):
        meth = getattr(self.source, action)
        meth(cookie)
        return self
```

which should be used as follows:

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
cookiedevice = CookieInput("cookies")
actions.w3c_actions.devices.append(cookiedevice)
actions.w3c_actions.cookie_action = CookieActions(cookiedevice)
[actions.w3c_actions.cookie_action.add_cookie(c) for c in cookies]
actions.perform()
```

This throws the analogous error:

> InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument from invalid
> argument: type of action must be the string 'keyUp', 'keyDown' or
> 'pause'   (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.77)

This is obviously an error from the chrome driver itself. Is there a more straight forward method of implementing this logic than rolling out a custom chrome driver implementation? Thanks, Best Regards.

Comment: If you want to add 1000-5000 cookies, are these for the same domain? Chrome only supports 180 cookies per domain see https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNet/11912/common-concepts/cookies-support and also are they persistent cookies as this will make a difference to some answers?

Comment: not for same domain

Comment: are they persistent cookies? presumably you are making requests to different domains then how many cookies per request on average?